# How can I change the size of an OpenCL buffer?

Tags: opencl

I want to simulate a particle system using OpenGL + OpenCL. It is working fine until I want to change the number of particles.

I create the buffers that contain the mass/velocity/position triplet.

```
cl_vbo_mem = cl::BufferGL(context, CL_MEM_WRITE_ONLY, vbo);
cl_v = cl::Buffer(context, CL_MEM_READ_WRITE, num_particles * sizeof(float) * 3);
cl_m = cl::Buffer(context, CL_MEM_READ_WRITE, num_particles * sizeof(float));
```

Then I upload them

```
/// set masses
command_queue.enqueueWriteBuffer(cl_m, CL_TRUE, 0, num_particles * sizeof(float), &initialMasses[0]);

/// set initial velocities
command_queue.enqueueWriteBuffer(cl_v, CL_TRUE, 0, num_particles * sizeof(float) * 3, &initialVelocities[0]);

/// set initial velocities
command_queue.enqueueWriteBuffer(cl_vbo_mem, CL_TRUE, 0, num_particles * sizeof(float) * 3, &initialPositions[0]);
```

When I increase the number of particles the program just simply crashes.

Comment: Please post a minimum working example that can be compiled and exhibits the error. That being said, `CL_MEM_WRITE_ONLY` declares a buffer that is write-only for the _kernel_, i.e. it cannot be read on the GPU. That's probably not what you want.

Comment: All the files and stuff can be located on [this](https://github.com/NadineAziz/gpu-homework) github repositoy. I commented where is the problem: GLCL_Interoperation_NBody/GLCL_Interoperation_NBody/MyApp.cpp and  from line 329 or in the ```void CMyApp::KeyboardDown(SDL_KeyboardEvent& key)``` function

Answer (score 0):

There isn't any official way in the API to change a buffer's size. If you know the maximum number of particles, then you could just allocate the size required for that. Or you could come up with some dynamic reallocation mechanism.